# Writing the dimension of a variable in latex

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am trying to write the information about the dimension of a vector like this

```
$M \epsilon R^N$
```

In the paper, they write it nicely, it looks nice. However, I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but it doesn't look good. Suggestions?

Comment: This is not very clear. Why "doesn't [this] look good"?

Answer (score 12):

I think you want to edit the style of fonts and symbols, but unless you give graphical details of what you want to achieve it is difficult to do it. The symbol for "belongs to" is obtained with `\in`. Then you can play with `\mathcal` if you want stylized R:

```
$M \in \mathcal{R}^N$
```

This looks like:

[image]

Comment: Or `\mathbb{R}`, which requires `\usepackage{amsfonts}` or, perhaps better, `\usepackage{amssymb}`.

Comment: @egreg Yes, there are many possibilities. I find it useful to look at one of those PDF compilations of latex symbols which allow you to quickly identify the symbol you are looking for and what package/command gives it to you. Something like "The comprehensive latex symbol list": www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf‎